# Cannot create a C++ project in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version 2018-12 (4.10.0) and have installed CDT (I verified this by going to installation details).

However, when I go to

File -> New -> Project -> C++ Project
the project types are missing, and I am not able to create a new C++ project.
How can I fix this?

Comment: What project type do you miss? E. g. for _Autotools_ you have to install also _C/C++ Autotools support_.

Comment: All project types are gone. None shows up.

Comment: Switching the perspective does not work either.

Comment: What did you exactly install (and how)? It seems the [Eclipse CDT Marketplace entry](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/complete-eclipse-cc-ide) points to the outdated update site `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/9.4/` instead of `http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/9.6/`.

Comment: Alright. Scratch that idea. Posting what I did. Note: I already have a functioning mingw install on my PC.

Comment: I did: Help -> Install New Software -> added 2018-12 http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2018-12 -> Programming Languages -> C/C++ Development Tools

Comment: I would have expected that to work.  I went with the "All sites" option and got CDT 9.6.0.201812111211. What did you get?

Comment: The same version

Comment: You have to check at least one item to install something. Which one did you check? What exactly is shown in the installation details? Is there something in the error log?

Comment: I checked the C/C++ Development Tools. Which includes C/C++ Common GDB Support, C/C++ Development platform, C/C++ DSF GDB Debugger Integration, C/C++ GNU Toolchain Build Support, C/C++ GNU Toolchain Debug Support

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I did:

1. Downloaded [eclipse-java-2018-12-R-win32-x86_64](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/2018-12/R/eclipse-java-2018-12-R-win32-x86_64.zip)
2. Unzipped.
3. Ran
4. Created new workspace (didn't want to risk blowing up my existing install)
5. Navigated Help->Install New Software.
6. Selected All Available Sites and waited for list to update.
7. Expanded Programming Languages
8. Selected C/C++ Development Tools
9. Clicked Next
10. Clicked Next
11. Read and Accepted License
12. Clicked Finish
13. Clicked Restart Now when it popped up.

C++ was not a New Project option, so

1. Changed to C++ perspective

C++ Project options now visible Hello World compiled and ran.

Caveats:

I have a fully functional MinGW install  with GCC 7.3 installed. (Cripes. Getting out of date. Should update)

I'm running Windows. Not sure how well (other than the obviously wrong link) this will work on a *nix box.

This is a minimal install. You may need Autotools, LLVM, or remote debugger support. Start with the simple stuff though. Get a Hello World project up and running, then add additional packages as your needs require.

Comment: Hmm... This is basically what I did except downloaded the macOS version since I have a macbook air. Maybe I should just reinstall eclipse and see if it works?

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue and I reinstalled Eclipse. For me this works. Also try to install the newest version.

Comment: Isn’t it the newest version though?

Comment: you installed from original sites

Comment: If *2018-12* isn't the most recent, I don't know what is. Sometimes an answer can be really short (Like "No."), but this is more comment than answer. You might be able to salvage it by expanding on it and adding some backing information.

Comment: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2018-12/r/eclipse-ide-cc-developers

Comment: That's not what the Asker is asking for. They want to add onto the Java IDE. It used to work, but I do so little Java work these days I stopped installing and adding to the Java edition years ago.

Answer (score 0):

When I uninstalled Eclipse and reinstalled it, all the project types appeared. It could have been an Eclipse bug...